# Remove compared objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, ios5

I have two *NSMutableArray*'s [***nowEvents*** and ***todayEvents***] with a list of events.

For the first array I'd like to remove the events that are happening today

```
myEventClass *nowEvent = [appDelegate.nowEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And for the 2nd one, the events that are happening now

```
myEventClass *todayEvent = [appDelegate.todayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The date,

```
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // Set the required date format
NSString *nowDate = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<event>
<name>My EventName</name>
<start_time>2011-10-13 19:30:00 +0200</start_time>
<end_time>2011-10-09 21:30:00 +0200</end_time>
</event>
```

Note: I'm parsing an xml list with today event list and adding it to two `NSMutableArray`s [`nowEvents` and `todayEvents`]

Want to have two sections with events: those which are happening today (in the current day) & now (haven't finished yet or are happening now); that's why I need to compare with date

How I'm amble to remove objects from these `NSMutableArray`s?

**nowEvent** - I need to compare with current (now) date
**todayEvent** - I need to compare with today date

Comment: That's all or you are still typing?

Comment: I don't really get the question

Comment: @el.severo, Add more context to the question. Its not clear now.

Comment: I don't catch the question. Maybe you could add a `?` somewhere :-)

Comment: @Oliver: ...sorry, updated my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[your_array removeObjectAtIndex: give_index_here ];
```

Comment: ok, that's the method which I have to use but how to compare them (the arrays); I want to compare them also...

Comment: You have event name and date... so what is the problem.... first get all Today event and store them into an temp array. Then one by one first compare event name match then check date of that event.. if both are equal then remove them from array.....